# Firefox cookies on Linux

Tags: firefox-3

Im using Firefox 3 now. I found out that cookies are stored inside a database file called cookies.sqlite

Is there any way that I can make my Firefox saves it cookies inside a txt ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you still have this problem 2 years later..

You can use sqlite3 in Python to retrieve the data from cookies.sqlite. The current version of Firefox is 15.0.1 and there have been a few changes to the format of the database since Firefox 3. You didn't say whether you are on Windows or Linux, but if you want to see what's in the cookies.sqlite file with SQLite Expert Personal 3.4.31.2253 or later will show you what is there. That is a Windows only application, but there are many Linux based SQlite browsers available. Just beware that SQLite Browser on SourceForge uses a version of the SQLite package that is too old to read the current Firefox files..